# How to allow long autocomplete search list in laravel

Tags: laravel, autocomplete

I'm using Laravel 5 to create a hotel booking system, which will integrate with third-party API for searching hotels all over the world.

In search form, there is a location field, where user can type city which they want to visit, and a autocomplete dropdown will show according to entered text.

The problem I'm facing is: there are too many cities from all over the world. The list is more than 10 thousand cities. The webpage keeps loading and unresponsive due to this field.

How can I put in all the cities in autocomplete list like what Expedia is showing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://community.algolia.com/places/ Good Luck!

Comment: This is a good idea, but the third-party API provider gives ID on each city, and ID is used to search hotels. So I still need to put in the whole list from API provider...

Comment: If you count only 10k cities; use Redis as cache layer with `id => name` pair and use https://redis.io/commands/scan; maintaining cluster of ElasticSearch or SOLR seems easy (and cheap) but its not. Regarding ElasticSearch you can see this youtube video 6.5/10 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waTWeJeFp4A

Answer (score 0):

Websites like these (probably) use techniques like [ElisticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) or [SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).
However Laravel also makes it possible to use a third party service like Algolia. However the first 2 you can install on your own server. Algolia is payd for.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scout

So I would suggest using Laravel Scout as your question is tagged Laravel. However the recommended external service is quite expensive after some time. Personally I would recommend Elasticsearch. There apparantly is even a package to make the connection between your app and the Elasticseach service easier: https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver

http://okfnlabs.org/blog/2013/07/01/elasticsearch-query-tutorial.html

Comment: @Kyslik Well I could flag the question as too broad, as search is a broad domain in computer science. However I started by pointing in the direction that there are supporting services built because of this that are the industry standard. And yes I'm thinking of better explaining or linking to a broader answer.

Comment: Well I did exactly that (flag as broad / recommend for 3rd party tool). I think we can help the OP via comments and get this question deleted / closed.

Comment: Are you sure you want to link to 5/6 year old resource?

Comment: @Kyslik But although there are many solutions this still is a valid problem I see solved in very bad ways even in the company I currenty work. Colleagues build json files that are a subset of the data or they build wildcard SQL queries. I think this answer might direct people searching for search in webapps maybe make a better decision,

Comment: Oh I agree; this is a big problem for small teams (maybe also for big ones) which never worked on search because there is so many options. I myself *built* a search that is fairly quick for the dataset I was given and we considered ES, SOLR as well, but server requirements alone are beyond what the project can support.