# How can I Refactor this search filter query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to search in multiple tables. I'm checking every single request object. For example: I am checking if the request has that object then concating it to my main query and getting that query result at the last. It doesn't looks and isn't good. How can I make this search query filter better in laravel? 
**Note: I have searched questions in stackoverflow but they are dealing with only one model.**

```
$query = DB::table('clients')
        ->leftjoin('ecommerce_contacts','ecommerce_contacts.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
        ->select('ecommerce_contacts.*', 'clients.*')
        ->where('clients.is_deleted', '=', '0');

        if(!is_null($request->fname)){
            $query+=->where('clients.fname', 'like', '%$request->fname%');
        }
        if(!is_null($request->lname)){
            $query+=->where('clients.lname', 'like', '%$request->lname%');            
        }
        if(!is_null($request->gender)){
            $query+=->where('clients.sex', $request->sex);            
        }
        if(!is_null($request->number)){
            $query+=->where('ecommerce_contacts.sex', 'like', $request->number);            
        }
        if(!is_null($request->registered_date)){

        }
        if(!is_null($request->purchase)){

        }
        $client = $query->get();        
        $data = json_encode($clients);
        return $data;
```

Comment: Have a look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535661/how-to-allow-long-autocomplete-search-list-in-laravel/53535691#53535691

Answer (score 3):

Use [conditional clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses):

```
DB::table('clients')
    ->leftjoin('ecommerce_contacts','ecommerce_contacts.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
    ->select('ecommerce_contacts.*', 'clients.*')
    ->where('clients.is_deleted', '=', '0')
    ->when(request()->has('fname'), function ($query) {
         return $query->where('clients.fname', 'like', '%' . request()->fname . '%');
    })
    ->when(request()->has('lname'), function ($query) {
         return $query->where('clients.lname', 'like', '%' . request()->lname . '%');
    })
    ->when(request()->has('gender'), function ($query) {
         return $query->where('clients.sex', '=', request()->gender);
    })
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query=DB::table('clients')
            ->leftjoin('ecommerce_contacts','ecommerce_contacts.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
            ->select('ecommerce_contacts.*', 'clients.*')
            ->where('clients.is_deleted', '=', '0');

        $search_fields=['fname','lname','gender','number','registered_date','purchase'];
        foreach($search_fields as $key){
            if(!is_null($key)){
                $query->orWhere('clients.'.$key, 'LIKE', '"%" . '.$request->$key.' . "%"');
            }
        }
        $client = $query->get();
        $data = json_encode($client);
        return $data;
```

Comment: I'm giving you a upvote because it's good for a search on a single model with same search pattern. But what if I want to search for the registered_date with the query in_between? Any other way around?

Comment: if($key=='register_date'){
               $key='created_at';
            }

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted `@DigitalDrifter` 's answer because i liked it but I prefer my filter pattern.
Have a look at this:

```
$query = DB::table('clients')
    ->leftjoin('ecommerce_contacts','ecommerce_contacts.client_id', '=', 'clients.id')
    ->select('ecommerce_contacts.*', 'clients.*')
    ->where('clients.is_deleted', '=', '0');

    !isset($request->fname)  ?: $query->where('clients.fname', 'like', '%$request->fname%');
    !isset($request->lname)  ?: $query->where('clients.lname', 'like', '%$request->lname%');            
    !isset($request->gender) ?: $query->where('clients.sex', $request->sex);            
    !isset($request->number) ?: $query->where('ecommerce_contacts.sex', 'like', $request->number);     

$client = $query->get();        
$data = json_encode($clients);

return $data;
```

I think this is more readable and requires less line of code.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.